# What are these () in ES6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I see this code:

```
const enhance = withHandlers({
    signIn: ({ signIn, provider }) => () => signIn(provider)
});
```

I understand `enhance` is a function. `signIn` is also a function, but what's the meaning of the empty `()` in between? Why can't it just be:

```
signIn: ({signIn, provider}) => signIn(provider)
```

Comment: `signIn` is a function that returns a function. The returned function (when you call `signIn`) is `() => signIn(provider)`. It has no arguments. Whether  `enhance` is a function or not, cannot be determined without knowing what `WithHandlers` returns.

Comment: `enhance` is a very abstract name for this highly specific funtion

Comment: Do a little research on ES6 "arrow functions".  There are a lot of articles on them.  They will explain the `()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The `()` is part of the arrow function. It's a function that returns a function. Let me break it down:

```
signIn: ({ signIn, provider }) => () => signIn(provider)
        ^                      ^   ^
     Destructuring        Implicit No argument
     assignment           return   arrow function
     for arguments
```

The property `signIn` is a method that takes in an object argument and returns a function which executes `signIn(provider)`.

Your version:

```
signIn: ({signIn, provider}) => signIn(provider)
```

Does not return a function that executes `signIn(provider)`, it returns the return value of `signIn(provider)`.